# Not quite clear how join operation works in ruby arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, join

I'm reading Chris Pine's Learn to Program and I'm on Ch 7 discussing array methods. https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/chap_07.html

One example using the join operation is

```
foods = ['artichoke', 'brioche', 'caramel']

puts foods.join('  :)  ') + '  8)'
```

and the output is

```
artichoke  :)  brioche  :)  caramel  8)
```

I am not clear why the :) is added after artichoke and brioche while 8) is added after caramel.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 foods.join('  :)  ') + '  8)' 
 #  artichoke  :)  brioche  :)  caramel  8)
 a =  foods.join('  :)  ')
 # artichoke  :)  brioche  :)  caramel
 a + '  8)' 
 #  artichoke  :)  brioche  :)  caramel  8)
```

Join returns string with separator injected between elements, to which string you add `'  8)'`

Answer (score 1):

The join call is finished after the last element of the array (caramel), then you add 8) to the string created by join via string concatenation, which is what + does to strings.